# React-Bootstrap carousel slider: how to detect current slide in display

Tags: reactjs, slider, react-bootstrap, bootstrap-carousel

I have a bootstrap slider (through the library: React-Bootstrap) and would like to find a way to detect the current slide in display (through classes code and not hooks). Here is the Slider component:

```
//import image1, image2, image3

class HeroSlider extends Component {

  handleSelect(){
    console.log('this sets the slide, but I just want to know the index of current slide')
  }

  render(){
  return (
    <Carousel indicators={false} controls={false} pause={false} onSelect={this.handleSelect()}>
      <Carousel.Item>
        <img className="d-block w-100" src={image1} alt="First slide" />
      </Carousel.Item>
      <Carousel.Item>
        <img className="d-block w-100" src={image2} alt="Third slide" />
      </Carousel.Item>
      <Carousel.Item>
        <img className="d-block w-100" src={image3} alt="Third slide" />
      </Carousel.Item>
    </Carousel>
  );
      }
}

export default HeroSlider
```

How could I go about this? Thank you.

Comment: You have to make the carousel a **controlled** component, and track the active index in state. See the docs: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/carousel/#controlled

Comment: I saw the documentation, but maybe because I am not good with hooks all I could get from it is that you can set the index using `activeIndex` and `onSelect`. If you could post an aswer here on how to track the slide via state (using activeIndex and/or onSelect), and using a class-based component, I would be very thankful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, here is how I solved it:

The functions/properties provided with react-bootstrap carousel won't help in detecting a change in slide index, they will just allow you to set it.

I wanted to have an image background slider that infinitely rotates while stopping at each image for 3 seconds. So I ended up just setting the state to update the index every 3 seconds using an interval function. Here is the code:

```
class HeroSlider extends Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    this.state = {
      index: 0,
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.interval = setInterval(
      () => this.setState({ index: (this.state.index + 1) % 7 }), 
      3000
    );
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }

  render(){
  return (
    <Carousel indicators={false} controls={false} pause={false} onSelect={this.handleSelect()}>
      <Carousel.Item>
        <img className="d-block w-100" src={image1} alt="First slide" />
      </Carousel.Item>
      <Carousel.Item>
        <img className="d-block w-100" src={image2} alt="Third slide" />
      </Carousel.Item>
      <Carousel.Item>
        <img className="d-block w-100" src={image3} alt="Third slide" />
      </Carousel.Item>
    </Carousel>
  );
      }
}

export default HeroSlider
```

Now if I want to detect current slider index I simply acces this.state.index.

Answer (score 0):

I built one too and I used this for the indexes:

```
const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);

const handleSelect = (selectedIndex, e) => {
  setIndex(selectedIndex);
};
```

to detect the current slide for styling you can use class="active carousel-item".

Comment: Thank you, but I want to detect the active class to style something else, so I want to detect it through code (when a certain slide is visible, call a function that is passed in props, that will style another element). So detecting it through CSS isn't going to be helpful